# How does one index a series of points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following two situations:

```
arr2d = numpy.zeros((50,50))

arr2d[10,10] = 1
arr2d[11,11] = 1
arr2d[12,12] = 1

indexer = numpy.where(arr2d == 1)

identically_typed_indexer = (numpy.asarray([1,1]),numpy.asarray([2,2]),numpy.asarray([3,3]))

arr2d[indexer] # works fine
arr2d[identically_typed_indexer] # fails

# try the numpy meshgrid formulation ((1,2,3),(1,2,3))
arr2d[zip(*identically_typed_indexer)] # fails

# at this point I had ruled out the correct answer (feels like a bug there)

# whereas 
arr2d[list(zip(*identically_typed_indexer))] # worked

# had to trigger the lazy eval
```

How do I construct a series of indexing points that numpy will not give up on?

---

In retrospect, the failure of `zip(*identically_typed_indexer)` feels like a flaw/bug.

Comment: Look at `indexer`.  It's a tuple with 2 arrays, one for each dimension of `arr2d`.  `arr2d[x, y]` is the same as `arr2d[(x,y)]` or `idx = (x,y)` followed by `arr2d[idx]`.

Comment: @hpaulj I ruled that out a long time ago with `zip(*identically_typed_integer)`, which failed.

Comment: @hpaulj it was a situation where I had to *know* what the answer was to get it to work after `zip(*identically_typed_integer)` failed. Or test the semantically identical expression a few different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to index *n* points of *m* dimensions, your indexer needs to be formatted as *m* arrays of size *n*.

In your 2D case, you need one *n*-sized array of the `x` coordinates, and one *n* sized array of the `y` coordinates.

Try using this instead:

```
identically_typed_indexer = (numpy.asarray([1,2,3]),numpy.asarray([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [86]: identically_typed_indexer = (numpy.asarray([10,10]),numpy.asarray([11,11]),numpy.as
    ...: array([12,12]))
In [87]: identically_typed_indexer
Out[87]: (array([10, 10]), array([11, 11]), array([12, 12]))
```

`list(zip(*...))` is a list transpose idiom:

```
In [88]: list(zip(*identically_typed_indexer))
Out[88]: [(10, 11, 12), (10, 11, 12)]
```

In Py2 `zip` produced a tuple (or list?), but in py3 it's, as you say, lazy.

Indexing with it works, but triggers an warning (in newer versions).  Devs are trying to clean up some old syntax

```
In [89]: arr2d[_]
<ipython-input-89-c0d885413ddb>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  arr2d[_]
Out[89]: array([1., 1., 1.])

In [90]: tuple(zip(*identically_typed_indexer))
Out[90]: ((10, 11, 12), (10, 11, 12))
In [91]: arr2d[tuple(zip(*identically_typed_indexer))]
Out[91]: array([1., 1., 1.])

In [92]: np.nonzero(arr2d)
Out[92]: (array([10, 11, 12]), array([10, 11, 12]))
```

`where/nonzero` produces the required tuple of arrays:

```
In [92]: np.nonzero(arr2d)
Out[92]: (array([10, 11, 12]), array([10, 11, 12]))
```

unpacking the tuple may make the action a bit clearer.

```
In [93]: i,j=np.nonzero(arr2d)
In [94]: i
Out[94]: array([10, 11, 12])
In [95]: arr2d[i,j]            # arr2d[(i,j)]
Out[95]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

Often in python list and tuple are interchangeable, but in `numpy` the distinction is used to convey useful information in several contexts.  Indexing is one.  It may also help to realize that it's the comma that makes the tuple, not the ().

```
In [96]: 1,2
Out[96]: (1, 2)
In [97]: 3,
Out[97]: (3,)
```

This comparison might also be instructive:

Making an array from your list:

```
In [100]: np.array(identically_typed_indexer)
Out[100]: 
array([[10, 10],
       [11, 11],
       [12, 12]])
```

is the same thing as:

```
In [101]: np.argwhere(arr2d==1)
Out[101]: 
array([[10, 10],
       [11, 11],
       [12, 12]])
In [102]: np.transpose(np.nonzero(arr2d==1))
Out[102]: 
array([[10, 10],
       [11, 11],
       [12, 12]])
```

So another way to 'transpose` your original list

```
In [103]: np.array(identically_typed_indexer).T
Out[103]: 
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12]])
In [104]: tuple(np.array(identically_typed_indexer).T)
Out[104]: (array([10, 11, 12]), array([10, 11, 12]))
```

### edit

The FutureWarning says that the list will eventually be interpreted as:
`arr[np.array(seq)]`

```
In [110]: np.array(list(zip(*identically_typed_indexer)))
Out[110]: 
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12]])
In [111]: arr2d[_].shape
Out[111]: (2, 3, 50)
```

That's indexing the first dimension of `arr2d` with a (2,3) array, resulting in (2,3,50) shape (i.e. all of the last dimension)